# ¿De dónde proviene la expresión "botar la piedra"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, historia, venezuela

Se escucha en muchas partes de Venezuela la siguiente expresión:

> Me hiciste **botar la piedra**...

¿Cuál es el origen de dicha expresión?

Según [lachuleta.net](http://www.lachuleta.net/dic/components/com_diccionario/index.php?a=print&d=19&t=72):

> expresión usada para referirse al momento en que uno pierde la paciencia y se enfada o molesta.

Ese es su significado, pero, ¿su origen cuál es?, ¿de dónde proviene?, y ¿por qué se emplea de esta manera para expresar esta acción?

Comment: Resulta curioso que si se consulta la expresión en el diccionario de americanismos, [este dice](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=botar): "loc. verb. _Ch._ Satisfacer un hombre o un animal macho su apetito sexual." Es decir, se usa en Chile con otro significado completamente diferente.

Comment: He escuchado la frase en Colombia como: "sacar la piedra" con el mismo significado.

Comment: En Colombia decimos «sacar la piedra»

Answer (score 3):

La expresión, en sí misma, no está documentada de que provenga de ningún momento o tiempo en especial.

Se presupone que viene de la dolorosa expulsión de piedras en el riñón (cálculos urinarios) y el estado de ánimo que ello produce.
En este acto, se presupone un estado de 'furia', la cual encaja con tu descripcion de 'enfadarse/molestarse'

Esto se asume por la definición de "botar" de: 'Echar fuera, despedir'

Esta expresión esta vinculada con la expresión "sacar la piedra" que tiene el mismo sentido con la expulsión de las piedras del riñon.

---

También he leido en [*9 Cosas que los venezolanos decimos cuando estamos enojados*](https://matadornetwork.com/es/cosas-que-los-venezolanos-decimos-cuando-estamos-enojados/) que el termino *botar la piedra* se refiere a *sacar la piedra* que proviene del juego del dominó.

En algunas ocasiones ocurre que tienes una unica ficha para poder colocarla y tienes justo la ocasión, pero justo antes alguien te la quita y te deja sin jugada, eso hace que 'saques la piedra' y te enfadas.

De ahi proviene que se utilize cuando alguien se enfada/enoja.

Comment: pero entonces _botar la piedra_ en el sentido de _aligerar_ no encaja con lo que indica el OP que es su significado, ¿no?

Comment: @fedorqui ¿En que momento dice que su significado sea _aligerar_ ?

Comment: se supone que cuando echas una piedra del riñón es doloroso pero además aligera el dolor

Comment: creo que la segunda parte de la respuesta responde el tema, ¡gran descubrimiento!

Comment: La primera parte es lo que encontre tras hablar con un amigo semiologo y busquedas de internet, la segunda es una "curiosidad" que creo que se corresponde bastante con su procedencia.

Comment: En Colombia donde el dominó no es muy popular, también decimos "sacar la piedra". No me cuadra ese origen.

Answer (score 2):

Proviene de la historia de cronos al cual lo desterraría uno de sus hijos según los oráculos, así que el se los comía.

El día que nació Zeus su madre no se lo da de comer, en cambio envolvió piedras en una manta y se lo dio a Cronos.

Años después cuando Zeus creció y fue a derrocar a su padre el regurgito y vio que lo que le habían dado ese día no fue a Zeus si no piedras. De ahí se originó el dicho me saco la piedra.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Entra en contradicción con la otra respuesta, ¿podrías aportar referencias que sustenten tu hipótesis? Dale a [edit] para añadirlas, ¡gracias!

Comment: si tengas referencias, sería de gran ayuda.

Comment: No veo porque votan negativamente esta respuesta. Cierto que no tiene referencias pero la otra respuesta tampoco las tiene.

Comment: Es una teoría muy original e interesante

Answer (score 2):

Es posible que "Sacar la piedra" provenga de la tradición (campesina) de tener una piedra en la cocina como utensilio. En muchos lugares de Colombia, por ejemplo, se tenía una piedra lo suficientemente grande para usarse en diferentes tareas domésticas (como un martillo, para machacar la carne o la panela, entre otras). Cuando este preciado elemento se sacaba de la casa, usualmente por los niños, para usarse en tareas diferentes al hogar, la madre se enojaba, pues se corría el riesgo de que se extraviase y, por tanto, se tendría que conseguir otra con las características necesarias para que cumpliera su labor. "El niño me sacó la piedra".

Answer (score 2):

Sacar la piedra proviene de la frase bíblica "quién esté libre de pecado que arroje la primera piedra". Refiere a un enfado tan grande que uno podría apedrear incluso a un santo. Hay otra expresión colombiana relacionada que es "me la tiene afuera", también habla de la piedra que uno por enfado está a punto de lanzar.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Escuché una vez de un estudiante, que dicha expresión proviene de un fenómeno que ocurre a los Zamuros cuando algún intruso interviene en su nido y roba sus polluelos, el animal se enfada de tal manera que bota una especie de piedra. Dicho elemento se llama en Venezuela "la piedra de Zamuro" y se usa como amuleto de buena suerte.

Answer (score 1):

La etimología popular no siempre es confiable, más bien resulta muy imprecisa. Muchos casos lo confirman.

La frase 'sacar la piedra' cuenta con una expresión análoga: 'sacar de quicio' Desquiciar es literalmente desencajar una ventana o puerta y por extensión semántica, descomponer algo, o exasperar a alguien.

Prefiero, a falta de datos, comparar, y a pesar de que el sentido de las frases hechas no se deduce sino por el conjunto de las palabras que la forman, no por palabras aisladas, 'sacar' es 'colocar algo fuera de lugar' y 'quicio' es la parte donde encaja una puerta o ventana para girar. Sacar de quicio, es colocar a alguien fuera de sí, 'sacar la piedra' también.

Muy usada en Venezuela con la variante pronominal 'me' "Me saca la piedra".

Por cierto, el Mono Kini de Carlos Donoso, el ventrílocuo, usaba mucho la frase:  "Me saca la piedra"  Que en paz descanse

Comment: bienvenido al sitio! Te animo a visitar [answer] y [tour], pues si eres buen aficionado a la lengua seguro que podrás aportar muchísimo a [spanish.se]

Answer (score 0):

La historia de la piedra de Zamuro es diferente, el no la 'saca' la busca al río (jordán en la historia original) y la trae al nido para recuperar los huevos dañados, no para que aparezcan los que fueron robados, así que no encaja mucho

Comment: Buenas, bienvenido al sitio, ¿puedes poner un enlace o un extracto de esa historia? ¿Donde aparece originalmente? ¿En la biblia? Juraría que en la otra respuesta hablan de pájaros reales, no mitológicos

Answer (score 0):

Me parecen bien sus teorías , pero creo que es más sencillo, una persona en estado colérico llegará al punto de gritar con mucho fuerza lo cual contrae los músculos del tórax y presiona sobre los riñones , puede que si tiene cálculos le provoque cólicos nefriticos o hasta bote la piedra , es mi teoría, si quieren hagan la prueba , griten  con todas sus fuerzas como si cantarán metalgore con mala técnica vocal,  es decir con rabia,y verán que se produce una contractura leve en la musculatura en la parte posterior de los riñones, es solo una teoría mía,pero no me extrañaría que la sabiduría popular recoja este hecho en esa frase